# whoosh issues with django forum apps

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-apps, whoosh

Trying to get some forum apps up and running. Cant get anything to work. With djangobb forums, and the pybb-demo im getting

```
The 'whoosh' backend requires the installation of 'Whoosh'. Please refer to the documentation.
```

Have downloaded haystack as well as whoosh seperatley and loaded them via python setup.py install, but it dosent seem all there. I cant find the extra missing files on the web either, so i though id ask what this issue could be brought about by.

When i install

```
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
```

It finishes doing its thing. But in that install dir there is no whoosh folder. The closest thing is django_whoosh-0.0.0-py2.6.egg. But the only py file init is a managers.py

I also get

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Whoosh in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

Its not, its just not there, what the?

Comment: Try installing whoosh with command: "easy_install whoosh", does the problem persist ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure whoosh is installed, you should check the install directory path and make sure it's included as part of the project libraries.

Using the django shell:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

That should display the available library paths for the project. I use whoosh and mine appears over there.

Comment: nope, no whoosh. I have followed all instructions as to how to install it. It shouldnt be bloody difficult. Its just the files arnt there. The one i downloaded, just has stuff all files init, like 4.py files. Its the only whoosh download i could find. ,

Comment: weird, I installed haystack and whoosh over buildout, using the following repos: git://github.com/toastdriven/whoosh.git and git://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git . Installed egg dirs are: Whoosh-2.3.0-py2.6.egg and django_haystack-1.2.6-py2.6. Didn't get any issues at all

Comment: Ok i got it working. Dont know what i was doing wrong, i just sought of suddenly appeared. Sorry, no answer as to what i was doing wrong.